# Cardinality of Binary sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Two questions I encountered in my last Set Theory HW.

1) Let T be a set of all Binary sequences that do not contain 2 consecutive zeros (ex. $100111010\notin T$). Let B be a set that contains all Binary sequences. 
Do B and T have the same Cardinality?
Does T have the same Cardinality as the set that contains all natural series ($|T|=|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$)?

To the first question I answered yes since:

Each binary number can be view as a natural number , B is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ thus $|B|= \aleph_0$. I very similarly take care of T and prove $|T|=\aleph_0$.

To the seconed I answered no since Cantor's Diagonal Argument proves $|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$.

Is this the way to go about it? am I correct?

2) Prove $|X|<|\{0,1,2\}^X|$. I know Cantor's Theorem gives $|X|<|\{0,1\}^X|$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is $B$ the set of finite binary sequences, or the set of all binary sequences (including infinite sequences) ?

Comment: For $(2)$, do you see why $\vert \{0, 1\}^X\vert\le \vert \{0, 1, 2\}^X\vert$?

Comment: @peter the question doesn't expand on it, but I guess they mean finite numbers since infinite ones aren't technically binary numbers.... how would it alter the answer?

Comment: @noahschweber cause there's the obvious 1:1 function from one to the other?

Comment: @user254509 Yup, that's right. So if Cantor's theorem tells you that $\vert X\vert<\vert \{0,1 \}^X\vert$, and you know $\vert \{0, 1\}^X\vert\le\vert\{0, 1, 2\}^X\vert$, then . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber ohh...see I thought i'd have to rewrite cantor's proof in some way....thanks a lot....say, so basically I can prove by induction up to $|\mathbb{N}^X|$, can't I?

Comment: You don't need induction at all: for any set $Y$, if $Y$ has at least two elements, then $Y^X$ has cardinality at least that of $2^X$, and hence $>$ that of $X$. Meanwhile, if $Y$ *doesn't* have at least two elements, then $Y$ either has one element - so $Y^X\equiv X$ - or $Y$ is empty - so $Y^X\equiv\emptyset$ (unless $X$ is empty - $\emptyset^\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}$ has one element :P).

Comment: @NoahSchweber ohhhhh....I see......thanks a lot !